# Why would the first Tg be higher than a rescan Tg of an epoxy by DSC?

Tags: differential-scanning-calorimetry

I have some small cured epoxy shafts I am cutting segments out of for checking Tg by DSC. First scan gave a Tg of 118 °C, follow on was 109 °C. Scans were repeated on a new sample of the shaft with similar results.

250 °F curing dicy based epoxy system. Neat resin before cure has exotherm onset at 127 °C and the curve's peak is 142 °C by DSC.

Any idea why the first scan would be higher than the rescan?

Comment: Because, while it *was* cured, it was far from being thermally inert. One could say, you cured it a little bit more with another heating. It's a bit like with cooking - reheated may taste better ;)

Comment: 250°F is 121°C ("C" is *Culoumb*, btw., and "F" is *Farad*). Yea, you probably re-cured your system. However I would expect the $T_g$ of an epoxy resin to go *up*, not down. What you saw in the first run was likely not the glass transition but the actual curing.Without seeing the actual curve, or at least the temperature profile, that's just guessing however.

Comment: What temperature range are you running, at what rate? What does the packaging of your epoxy say about curing time? And a *peak* indicates an endo-/exothermal process, like a reaction. Is there still a small peak in the second run?

Comment: related https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/dicyandiamide-dicy